# Can't authenticate using MongoEngine. PyMongo works. How do I get MongoEngine to authenticate?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm trying to authenticate for a MongoDB database using mongoengine.connect().  When I use pymongo.MongoClient() the code works perfectly, however mongoenine.connect() is throwing this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command createRole requires authentication
```

I believe the connection parameters are identical and MongoEngine uses PyMongo to connect anyways, so I am confused about what is wrong here.

I printed the MongoClients returned by PyMongo and MongoEngine and they were slightly different:

Pymongo MongoClient:

```
MongoClient(host=['x.x.x.x:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
```

MongoEngine MongoClient:

```
MongoClient(host=['x.x.x.x:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary())
```

Is the read_preference affecting my ability to connect somehow?

Here is the code making the calls:

```
user_admin_client = pymongo.MongoClient(
    f'mongodb://{usern}:{pswd}@x.x.x.x/my_db'
)
print(user_admin_client)

user_admin_client = mongoengine.connect(db='my_db',
                                        username=usern,
                                        password=pswd,
                                        host='x.x.x.x',
                                        alias='init'
                                                )
print(user_admin_client)
```

**How can I get MongoEngine to work?  What am I doing wrong here?**

**------ Update 5/9/19:**

I tried the following code:

```
user_admin_client = mongoengine.connect(
        f'mongodb://{usern}:{pswd}@x.x.x.x/my_db'
        )
    print(user_admin_client)
```

I got the following:

```
MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary())
...traceback...
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I'm a little confused as to why the MongoClient is now trying to connect to localhost, because my IP address is definitely correctly typed.  Even using `x.x.x.x:port` did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `host` parameter on connect

```
user_admin_client = mongoengine.connect(host='mongodb://{usern}:{pswd}@x.x.x.x/my_db')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong here.

Can you try using `Mongo URI` itself to connect through MongoEngine.

Something like:

```
user_admin_client = mongoengine.connect('mongodb://{usern}:{pswd}@x.x.x.x/my_db')
print(user_admin_client)
```